# product of complement of two different maximal ideals is the set of nonzero elements?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This question originated in my last question.

Let $A$ be a  **Dedekind domain**, and let $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}$ be two different maximal ideals of $A$.
Then we know $A_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{q}\cong S^{-1}A$ as $A$-algebras, where $S:=\{xy|\ x\in A\setminus \mathfrak{p}, y\in A\setminus \mathfrak{q}\}.$ Moreover, we know $S^{-1}A\cong \mathop{Frac}(A)$ by noting $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a DVR.

Now my question is that can we prove $S=A\setminus\{0\}$? Or are there some counterexamples?

This result clearly holds if $A$ is a PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $A=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ $=$ $\sqrt{-5}$. Put $\mathfrak{p}_2$ $=$ $(2,\alpha-1)$, $\mathfrak{p}_3$ $=$ $(3,\alpha-1)$ and $\mathfrak{q}_3$ $=$ $(3,\alpha+1)$. These are prime ideals of $A$. In fact, $2A$ $=$ $\mathfrak{p}_2^2$ and $3A$ $=$ $\mathfrak{p}_3\mathfrak{q}_3$. Note that $\alpha-1$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}_2\cap\mathfrak{p}_3$. And $\alpha-1$ is irreducible: its norm is $6$ and there are no elements $a+b\alpha$ (with $a,b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$) of norm $a^2+5b^2$ equal to $2$ or $3$. So if $\alpha-1$ $=$ $xy$ in $A$, one of $x$ and $y$ is a unit. But if $x$ is a unit, $y$ is both in $\mathfrak{p}_2$ and in $\mathfrak{p}_3$. So $\alpha-1$ cannot be written as a product of two elements with one in $A\setminus\mathfrak{p}_2$ and the other one in $A\setminus\mathfrak{p}_3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this example is suprising.